# How to make Django run a command only once per model

Tags: python, django

We're using django-MPTT for tree items and I have to create functionality for automatic email notifications when a tree item has been modified. Absolutely straight-forward using save signals but - if a parent item is modified, then n (n being number of childen items + parent item) emails are sent instead of just one (because parent's changes are automatically done to children). Is there a good way to prevent that and basically tell Django "Please send only one email per model"?

The best I've come up with is a kind of a hacky way (and a pretty bad hack): add a model to the database that is updated when the parent item is modified and with childrens always check that model before sending email. I.e. if `HiddenModel` exists, do not send email, else send email. And after like five seconds (probably in another thread) remove/undo modifications to that `HiddenModel` object. It would probably work, but performance-wise it's just bad, with all those database queries.

EDIT: Model: (shortened version for SO, probably has some errors in this form)

from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

```
class TreeItem(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    users = models.ManyToManyField('accounts.User', blank=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    @property
    def tree_path(self):
        if self.is_root_node():
            return []

        tree = self.get_ancestors(include_self=False, ascending=False)
        return list(map(lambda item: item.name, tree))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        is_new = self.pk is None
        if not is_new:
            prev_allowed_users = TreeItem.objects.get(pk=self.pk).users.all()

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        new_allowed_users = self.users.all()
        if is_new:
            self.send_access_email(list(new_allowed_users)) #TODO
        else:
            if prev_allowed_users != new_allowed_users:
                send_to = self.get_new_access_users(prev_allowed_users, new_allowed_users) # TODO
                self.send_access_email(send_to)

    def get_new_access_users(self, prev_users, new_users):
        send_to = []
        for user in new_users:
            if user not in prev_users:
                send_to.append(user)

        return send_to

    def send_access_email(self, recipient_list):

        email_content = 'example'

        email = EmailMessage(
            'subject',
            email_content,
            'ex@ample.com',
            recipient_list)

        print("Sending email to %s users" % str(len(recipient_list)))
```

Comment: Can you post your model? I think I can pretty much visualize what you're describing, but it always helps to have it in front of me.

Comment: @Travis Updated the question.

Comment: Does it still propagate to all the children if you use the actual post_save signal rather than overriding the save() method?

Comment: @MadWombat Unable to use post_save because I need to compare the data from before saving and the data that will be saved. But yes, I imagine it would, because all of the objects will be saved as well. Sorry that I mentioned signals, obviously I'm overriding `save()` not using signals - just a brain fart or whatever they call it.

Comment: Sounds like you are going to need some sort of locking mechanism to remember which tree item initiated the save. Since the updates all happen in the same thread, I don't think you really need a model for this. A simple python object should do.

Comment: @MadWombat Could you provide me with a simple example? I'm not really sure about how to store data in anywhere than the database. I thought of cache (server-side cache?), but I don't really know if it would work.

Comment: posted some code in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some sort of registry to figure out if your object is being saved externally or as part of a tree traversing cascade. It seems that using a class variable might be a more elegant way of doing this. Here is some pseudo-code to illustrate what I mean.

```
class TreeItem(MPTTModel):
    _save_registry = set()

    ... your model fields go here ...

    def is_save_locked(self):
        return any(p.id in TreeItem._save_registry for p in self.get_parents())

    def save_lock(self):
        TreeItem._save_registry.add(self.id)

    def save_release(self):
        TreeItem._save_registry.remove(self.id)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.is_save_locked:
             self.save_lock()
             ... do things only original save should do ...
             self.save_release()
        ... do things every save should do ...
        return super(TreeItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```